# How to store array values depending on a condition?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have variables of type `string, [int], bool`

```
var books:[String] = ["Hobbit","LOTR","Fellowship"]
var chaptersToRead:[[Int]] = [[1],[1,3],[2,3]]
var read:[Bool] = [false,true,true]
```

I have function `display()` so that I can see details about all the books individually

```
func display() -> [[Any]] {
    var output = [[Any]]()
    for i in 0..<books.count {
        output.append([books[i], chaptersToRead[i], read[i]])
    }
    return output
}
```

I like to store values of books in two arrays based on condition `if chaptersToRead = 1`, as follows

```
var booksAssigned:[String] = ["Hobbit","LOTR"]

var readStatus:[Bool] = [false,true]
```

I tried to get the above result by doing the following below which is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
var booksAssigned:[String] = []
var readStatus:[Bool] = []

for (index, books) in display().enumerated()
{
  if chaptersToRead.joined().contains(1)
  {
    //I am getting signal SIGABRT error here
    booksAssigned = books as! [String]
  }
}

for (index, status) in display().enumerated()
{
    if chaptersToRead.joined().contains(1)   
    {
        //I am getting signal SIGABRT error here
        readStatus = status as! [Bool]
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is an inappropriate data structure – you should use an array of structs instead.

Comment: try using struct as data type: struct Book{
    let name: String
    var chapters: [Int]
    var isRead: Bool
}

Comment: So I should use structs to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var booksAssigned:[String] = []
var readStatus:[Bool] = []

for (index, chapters) in chaptersToRead.enumerated() {
    if chapters.contains(1) {
        booksAssigned.append(books[index])
        readStatus.append(read[index])
    }
}

print(booksAssigned)
print(readStatus)
```

Edit: Edited as per @Nirav D's suggestion.

Comment: @Coder221 There is no need to make second loop of chapters you can simply use `if chapters.contains(1)` for that and append the array.

Answer (score 1):

Remove var keyword from if blocks. You have already declared those variables.

```
var booksAssigned:[Any] = []
var readStatus:[Any] = []

for (index, books) in display().enumerated()
{
    if chaptersToRead.joined().contains(1)
    {
        booksAssigned = books
    }
}

for (index, status) in display().enumerated()
{
    if chaptersToRead.joined().contains(1)
    {
        readStatus = status
    } 
}
```

This works.